# Find all onclick attributes and append a value to them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find all elements with an `onclick` attribute and append ";toggle()"

```
var originalAttribute = $('[onclick]').attr('onclick');
$('[onclick]').attr('onclick', originalAttribute + ';toggle()');
```

There is something obviously wrong, but what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('[onclick]').attr('onclick');` will return the value for the *first* matching element.

You need to do this for each element. Try this:

```
$('[onclick]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var originalAttribute = $this.attr('onclick');
    $this.attr('onclick', originalAttribute + ';toggle()');
});
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AXv9b/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

EDIT:

```
$('[onclick!=""]').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('onclick', $(this).attr('onclick') + ';toggle()');
});
```